# Simple security question - how to pass a params-like security code in everyday actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I have some situations where I want to be sure that one controller action (or route) can only be accessed by another controller action and not by being typed in. For example, I have a couple of 'switchboard' controller actions that resolve internal analytics, set initial values, then send different users off to their respective destinations (each destination has its own controller action).

An example of this situation: a user should only be able to view a record having gone through the switchboard action first.

Is one way to do this would be to involve perishable tokens somehow? (I am using AuthLogic in my app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar using a session. In my case an action had :

```
session[:boss_attack] = 1
```

and the other action had :

```
if session[:boss_attack] != 1
    redirect_to :action => 'index' and return
else
    session[:boss_attack] = 0
end
```

And then i would continue with the actual action. It seems to be working fine :)

Comment: @SpyrosP - isn't it true that session data can't be trusted? I'm looking for a way to be truly secure against a hacker who is really trying to gain access to places I want to keep safe.

Comment: care to explain -1 for whoever put it ?

Comment: SpyrosP - For clarity, I didn't give you a -1. :)

Comment: That's ok don't worry about, it's probably someone who has no clue whatsoever :)

Comment: @SpyrosP - quick question... if a user can click any of many `link_to`s, how can I set a session variable depending on which one they click? Session variables can only be set in a separate statement, isn't that right?

Comment: You can set the session variable depending on the action that they click. So, you just change the session variable inside the corresponding action.

Answer (score 0):

As @SpyrosP suggested, one option would be to use a session.

To clarify, the session should be a server-side session.  If you're using cookie sessions, you should consider another storage method.  Rails cookie storage sessions should be secure, but even the docs suggest using another method if you don't want the user to see the data (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore)

If you use server-side session store (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SessionStore) your  risk is reduced considerably.  The only thing stored on the client browser is a cookie that maps to a record on the server side.  Rails does all the heavy lifting to avoid session hijacking and fixation attacks.

Comment: are server-side sessions standard in Rails?